# Continuous p-adic function similar to q-adic norm

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Given two distinct primes $p,q$, I am looking for some notion of a $q$-adic valuation of $p$-adic numbers.  Obviously, I can define $f:\Bbb{Q}_p \to \Bbb{Q}_p$ by $f(x) = \begin{cases}|x|_q & x\in \Bbb{Q}_q \\ 1 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.  I was hoping that I could redefine $f$ to be continuous.  In other words, does there exist a continuous function $f \in C(\Bbb{Q}_p,\Bbb{Q}_p)$ such that for all $x \in \Bbb{Q}\setminus \{0\}$, $f(x) = |x|_q$?  Even better if this is true for any $x \in (\Bbb{Q}_p\cap \Bbb{Q}_q)\setminus \{0\}$. I know the q-adic norm is not continuous at zero in $\Bbb{Q}_q$, but since $\left||x|_q\right|_p=1$, I was hoping I might even be able to get continuity at zero, so long as $|f(0)|_p = 1$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by $x \in \mathbb{Q}_q$ given that $x \in \mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: $\Bbb{Q} \subset \Bbb{Q}_p$ and $\Bbb{Q}\subset \Bbb{Q}_q$ implies $\Bbb{Q}_p\cap \Bbb{Q}_q \neq \emptyset$.  So, the condition "if $x\in \Bbb{Q}_q$" makes sense even though $x\in \Bbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: I don't follow. If I say $x \in S$ and then have as an additional condition that $x \in T$, then $T$ needs to be a subset of $S$. But I don't see how $\mathbb{Q}_q$ is naturally a subset of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: Using the notation from your example, $S = (S\cap T) \cup (S\setminus T)$.  So, for any $x \in S$, either $x \in S\cap T\subseteq T$ or $x \in S\setminus T$.  So, given a function $g:T\to K$ (where $K\subseteq S\cap T$), I can define $f:S\to S$ by $f(x) = \begin{cases}g(x) & x\in T \\ s & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ (where $s\in S$ is arbitrary).  What this means is, if $x\in S\cap T \subset T$, then $x \in T$, so $f(x)=g(x)$.  If $x\in S\setminus T$, then we are in the "otherwise" case, so $f(x) = s$.

Comment: I still don't follow. What does $S \cap T$ mean if you haven't given me a common superset of which $S$ and $T$ are subsets?

Comment: $S\cap T$ means the intersection of $S$ and $T$.  There is a natural "common superset": $S\cup T$ (the union of $S$ and $T$).  By definition, $S\subseteq (S\cup T)$ and $T\subseteq (S\cup T)$.

Comment: I still don't follow. What is the "natural common superset" of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $\mathbb{Q}_q$? I am not aware of any natural ring in which these both sit as subrings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15077/discussion-between-slipeternal-and-qiaochu-yuan).

Comment: No. Here is an example of the kind of trouble you can get into if you're being as cavalier as you currently are about the distinction between a pair of sets and a pair of subsets of a common superset. What is $\mathbb{Q}(x)/(x^3 - 2) \cap \mathbb{R}$? The answer is "undefined because you haven't specified a common superset." There are three ways to embed $\mathbb{Q}(x)/(x^3 - 2)$ into $\mathbb{C}$, and those embeddings don't all have the same intersection with $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You should never, ever, ever take the intersection of a pair of sets unless you have in mind a particular superset of which they're subsets. The "ZFC intersection" of a pair of bare sets is almost never the construction you actually want because it depends very delicately on how you construct all of the sets involved, e.g. the intersection of $\mathbb{R}$ with anything else depends on whether you constructed $\mathbb{R}$ via Cauchy sequences or Dedekind cuts, and everything depends very delicately on how you construct ordered pairs, etc. In my opinion this is by far the worst defect of ZFC.

Comment: Ok, I see your points, and I appreciate the comments.  It is something to keep in mind as I continue investigating p-adic fields.  Honestly, though, I just need the q-adic valuation to be accurate on the rationals, and that embedding is well-understood.  I was just hoping to extend the q-adic valuation to the rest of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ in a way that would make sense algebraically and (I was hoping) would be continuous.  As sea turtles explained, an algebraic q-adic valuation exists, but cannot be constructed, and it is not possible for it to be continuous.

Comment: $\Bbb Q_\ell$ contains transcendental elements for any prime $\ell$ (can you prove this? consider cardinality), and so $\Bbb Q_\ell$ cannot be embedded into $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ for any prime. The next largest algebraically closed field up to isomorphism is $\Bbb C$, and there do exist embeddings $\Bbb Q_\ell\hookrightarrow\Bbb C$ for any prime $\ell$. (These are *abstract* maps; they are field homomorphisms but have no topological stipulations.) The problem here is that the intersection $\Bbb Q_p\cap\Bbb Q_q$ **depends** on which embeddings you pick, so it is still ill-defined.

Comment: @seaturtles: Of course.  Fermat's Little Theorem pretty much guarantees that $\Bbb{Q}_l$ will contain transcendental elements.  It will also contain the $n$-th cyclotomic field so long as $n|(l-1)$.  I understood from your original answer that the $q$-adic valuation that you described was not unique, but depended on the choice of embeddings.  I'm now considering analytic completions of the rationals, such as the completion with respect to the metric $d:\Bbb{Q}\times \Bbb{Q} \to [0,\infty)$ defined by $d(r,s) = \max\{|r-s|_p,|r-s|_q\}$.  In this completion, both p- and q-adic norms make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does there exist a continuous function $f:\Bbb Q_p\to\Bbb Q_p$ such that $f(x)=|x|_q$ for all $x\in\Bbb Q^\times$?

Continuity implies sequential continuity: $f(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)$.

Given any $p$-adic number $x\in{\Bbb Q}_p$ (in particular, any rational), there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge1}$ of rationals such that $x_n\to x$ in the $p$-adic topology but $|x|_q$ does not converge in $\Bbb Q_p$.

*Proof*. Pick any sequence of rationals $(x_n)_{n\ge1}$ such that $x_n\to x$ and $v_q(x_n)=0$ bounded from below, then form the new sequence $y_n=x_n+(p/q)^n$. We have $y_n\to x$ but $|y_n|_q=q^n$ for all sufficiently large $n$, which does not converge.

> Given two distinct primes $p,q$, I am looking for some notion of a $q$-adic valuation on $\Bbb Q_p$.

Their topologies are incompatible as we've seen, but if we forget about $\Bbb Q_p$'s topology we can put an absolute value on in that extends $|\cdot|_q$ on $\Bbb Q$, though not constructively (meaning we won't be able to write it out explicitly, we just know such an absolute value exists). Let $K$ be the underlying field of $\Bbb Q_p$ and let $\overline{K}$ be its algebraic closure. Since there is a unique algebraically closed field of every cardinality and characteristic up to isomorphism, there exists an isomorphism $\overline{K}\cong\overline{\Bbb Q_q}$. If we apply this isomorphism to the embedding $K\hookrightarrow\overline{K}$ we get an embedding $K\hookrightarrow\overline{\Bbb Q_q}$ and thus by transport of structure we can put a $q$-adic absolute value on $\Bbb Q_p$.

Comment: That explains a ton! Thank you very much!